# Unity C# Foam on wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I don't know how to search for my problem, as English is not my native language, the premise is, I want to make the effect of spraying foam on wall. I already did this with particles but i want to have a depth or "3D" effect so the splatter on the wall looks "foamy.

I don't need it to look realistic no physics or moving or anything just that it looks "3D" and not just painted on wall like a sticker and i just need one game object to have the desired effect.

Here is the image of the desired effect:
[image: foamy wall]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is tu used normal, bumped or height map textures on the walls, like on this tutorials:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterNormalMap.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterHeightMap.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wce3myavXLs

Comment: something like that, but i need this to happen mid game, i want to paint the texture like in the picture but the wall looks normal from start.